# Definition of support in Evans book partial differential equation.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convolution

**Definition.** Define $\eta\in C^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$ by

$$\eta(x) := \begin{cases} C\exp\left(\frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert^2-1}\right), & \mbox{if } \lvert x \rvert< 1 \\ 0 & \mbox{if } \lvert x \rvert\ge 1\end{cases}$$

the constant $C>0$ selected so that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\eta\;dx =1$.

For each $\varepsilon > 0$, set $$\eta_\varepsilon (x):= \frac{1}{\varepsilon^n}\eta\left(\frac{x}{\varepsilon}\right).$$ The functions $\eta_\varepsilon$ are $C^\infty$.
Evans book Partial Differential Equation said that
$$\text{supp}(\eta_\varepsilon)\subseteq B(0,\varepsilon).\tag1$$

**My Solution**

Suppose that $x\in\text{supp}(\eta_\varepsilon)$, then $\eta_\varepsilon (x)\ne 0$ and therefore $$ \left| \frac{x}{\varepsilon} \right|<1$$ and the $x\in B(0,\varepsilon)$.

> **Question 1.** It's correct?

Now we observe that $\eta_\varepsilon (x)\ne 0$ for all $|x|<\varepsilon$, then by closed support definition we have that $$\text{supp}(\eta_\varepsilon)=\overline{B}(0,\varepsilon).\tag2$$

> **Question 2.** Aren't $(1)$ and $(2)$ contradictory? Where am I wrong? What definition of support does Evans use at this point?

Comment: There is no reason to make everything `\Large`.  The usual displaymath style is sufficient for readability.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator{supp}{supp}$You should also be careful about what you mean by "support".  My understanding is that the $\supp(u) = \overline{\{x : u(x) \ne 0\}}$, i.e. the closure of the non-zero set.  Thus there may be $x \in \supp(u)$ with $u(x) = 0$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Do you know what Evans means by support in the text partial differential equations?

Comment: See page 699.  Evans uses $B(x,r)$ to denote a *closed* ball.  He uses $B^0(x,r)$ for an open ball.